# CSV UPLOAD TO MYSQL WITH PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, overwrite

Hi I currently have this php file that will import csv data into mysql database each time its triggered however I want it to overwrite the current data in the database not just keep adding to it everytime it is triggered . Here is the file minus my details :

```
<?php

//database connection details
$connect = mysql_connect('mydetails','mydetails','mydetails');

if (!$connect) {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('mydetails',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','myfile location');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "my file"; 


if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
   fgetcsv($handle);   
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
      $col[$c] = $data[$c];
    }

 $col1 = $col[0];
 $col2 = $col[1];
 $col3 = $col[2];
 $col4 = $col[3];

// SQL Query to insert data into DataBase
$query = "INSERT INTO     orders(OrderNumber,OrderCustomer,OrderReqdQty,OrderStatus)     VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."')";
$s     = mysql_query($query, $connect );
  }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: TODO:

1. Check the `OrderNumber` if it is existing in your DB

2. if existing do an UPDATE STATEMENT

3. If NOT existing do and INSERT STATEMENT

Comment: <insert obligatory **dont use the mysql driver, its dead** message here>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've got unique OrderNumber. Add proper key to table and use ON DUPLICATE UPDATE syntax.

More on this topic here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

--- EDIT ---
First you need to add correct unique key in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE orders add UNIQUE(OrderNumber);
```

This query should add unique key and from now on there are no duplicated OrderNumber possible. If there are any in database this query will throw proper error message in your face. If you simply try add another entry with the same OrderNumber you will be also gracefully welcomed by error message.

Now you modify your script with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders(OrderNumber, OrderCustomer, OrderReqdQty, OrderStatus) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE OrderCustomer='".$col2."', OrderReqdQty='".$col3."', OrderStatus='".$col4."'";
```

Then everytime OrderNumber is found within table instead of throwing an error, there will be UPDATE performed on this very row.

Comment: I am pretty new to this would you mind showing me on the above code how to implement this. I do have the correct database table as the php file is working but like I say it just keeps adding/duplicating the info and not overwriting it . Thank you in advance to everyone :)